# Puppet serving plugins over nginx throws 404s

Tags: nginx, puppetmaster

I migrated my puppet master setup to run under thin with files being served from nginx.

Module files are served great, but plugin files don't appear to work. The logs think that the agents are requesting urls like `/production/file_content/plugins/puppet/provider/exec/powershell.rb` and nginx is therefore throwing a 404 because no such path like that exists. This works fine on WEBrick.

In theory, this should be a simple case of writing a rewrite rule similar to the modules rule below. However, a lot of these providers are within modules, so this particular provider is in `/etc/puppet/modules/powershell/lib/puppet/provider/exec/powershell.rb`.

How do I map from the request URL to the actual plugin, when they could be scattered around various module directories?

My nginx config looks like this:

```
upstream puppetmaster-thin {                                                                                                                                                          
    server  unix:/var/run/puppet/puppetmasterd.0.sock;                                                                                                                                
    server  unix:/var/run/puppet/puppetmasterd.1.sock;                                                                                                                                
    server  unix:/var/run/puppet/puppetmasterd.2.sock;                                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                                                                     

server {                                                                                                                                                                              
    listen  8140;                                                                                                                                                                     
    root    /etc/puppet/rack;                                                                                                                                                         

    ssl                     on;                                                                                                                                                       
    ssl_session_timeout     5m;                                                                                                                                                       
    ssl_certificate         /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/gcspuppet01.pem;                                                                                                                
    ssl_certificate_key     /var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/gcspuppet01.pem;                                                                                                         
    ssl_client_certificate  /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem;                                                                                                                        
    ssl_crl                 /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crl.pem;                                                                                                                        
    ssl_verify_client       optional;                                                                                                                                                 
    ssl_ciphers             SSLv2:-LOW:-EXPORT:RC4+RSA;                                                                                                                               

    proxy_read_timeout  120;                                                                                                                                                          
    proxy_redirect      off;                                                                                                                                                          

    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;                                                                                                                                        
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;                                                                                                                                 
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                                                                   
    proxy_set_header   X-Client-Verify  $ssl_client_verify;                                                                                                                           
    proxy_set_header   X-Client_DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;                                                                                                                             
    proxy_set_header   X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;                                                                                                                             
    proxy_set_header   X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;                                                                                                                             


    location /production/file_content/ {                                                                                                                                              
    location /production/file_content/extra_files/ {                                                                                                                              
        alias /etc/puppet/files/;                                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                             
    rewrite ^/production/file_content/modules/([^/]+)/(.*) /$1/files/$2;                                                                                                          
    break;                                                                                                                                                                        
    root /etc/puppet/modules/;                                                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                                                                 
    location / {                                                                                                                                                                      
    proxy_pass          http://puppetmaster-thin;                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue lay with the fact that nginx was effectively trying to serve up static any request to `/production/file_content/`. The problem with this is that while this is useful for serving up files from modules under `/production/file_content/modules/`, it hijacks `/production/file_content/plugins`.

Because the plugins paths are 'magic', they need to be handled by the puppet master daemon, and not by nginx. The solution is to write a better nginx config file:

```
location /production/file_content/extra_files/ {                                                                                                                                  
    alias /etc/puppet/files/;                                                                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                                                                 
location /production/file_content/modules/ {                                                                                                                                      
    rewrite ^/production/file_content/modules/([^/]+)/(.*) /$1/files/$2;                                                                                                          
    break;                                                                                                                                                                        
    root /etc/puppet/modules/;                                                                                                                                                    
}
```